# Navigation buttons and div

Tags: html, css

I have an ugly navigation bar with 5 buttons and a div under the bar.

1) How do I place the buttons in the middle of navigaton bar?
2) How to make them stay on the same line even if they don't have enough space on the screen? 
3) How to make div take the rest of space (height)?

**html**

```
<body>
    <nav id="wrap">

          <ul class="navbar">

             <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>

             <li><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>

             <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>

             <li><a href="#">Other</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                </ul>         
             </li>

             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>

          </ul>

</nav>


<div id="divdiv"> div div div div div </div>


</body>
```

**css**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background:#FFF;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#wrap   {
        width: 100%; 
        height: 80px; 
        margin: 0; 

        position: relative; 
        background-color: #00BF5F;
        margin-bottom:40px;
    }


    .navbar {
        padding-left:0px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }

        .navbar li {
            height: auto;
            width: 150px;  
            float: left;  
            text-align: center;  
            list-style: none;  
            font:  bold 14px Tahoma;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #00BF5F;
            }


    .navbar a {                         
        padding: 31px 0;  
        text-decoration: none;  
        color: white; 
        display: block;
        }



     .navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color: orange; } 



     .navbar li ul  {
        display: none; 
        height: auto;
        border-top:1px solid white;
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;         
        }               

    .navbar li:hover ul     { display: block;  }


    .navbar li ul li {background-color: orange; } 


    .navbar li ul li a { padding:5px; }


    .navbar li ul li a:hover    {background-color: red;}




    #divdiv {
        width:960px;
        height:500px;
        background:red;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nfTC5/

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.navbar {
   min-width: 750px;
}
.navbar li { 
   line-height: 80px;
}
.navbar li ul li {
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nfTC5/1/)

Comment: but how to put buttons in the center of nav? live the div under it